# How to Identify whether pagenumber is on/off of a .pptx(MS powerpoint) file?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, powerpoint-2007

I would like to know if there is a way of identify whether pagenumber property is enabled or disabled for a MS Powerpoint file?

So far my research lead me to this [post](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.powerpoint/PowerPoint-2007-Page-Numbering)

In this we need to read the slides of the presentation, in order to use
HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible property.

Is there a global way of identifying this by just taking the presentation as a whole?

Ex: something like, Presentation.SlideNumber.Visible ???

PS: Is there a way to do this for .ppt files as well?

Thanks
Yasindu.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but the [PowerPoint Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265987%28v=office.12%29.aspx) indicates you want to look at:
`Presentation.SlideMaster.HeaderFooters(i).SlideNumber.Visible`

Answer (score 0):

Each slide can have the page number visible or not.

```
Dim oSl as Slide
For Each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides
If oSl.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible Then
  Debug.Print "Your slides, if not days, are numbered"
Else
  Debug.Print "Slides without number.  This one, anyhow."
End If
```